# Computer shutting down randomly - possibly overheating?

Tags: cpu, shutdown, fan, cooling, temperature

My computer will randomly shut down, usually it's while playing a game or doing a high processing task, and the last thing I will hear is my loud fan. But sometimes the fan won't be too loud and I'll just be doing some basic internet browsing when it abruptly shuts down.
This has only started happened recently, when the only thing I have done is add more fans.

Is there a way to find out for sure if my computer is overheating?
Is it possible for me to save temperatures to a text file so I will know the temperatures right before my computer shuts down, to find out if it really is overheating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to check this is to download and install a program called Speccy: https://www.piriform.com/speccy/download

This program will list your hardware and the temperature for those it can read.

Comment: well I currently use speedfan to read temperatures, but is it possible to save temperatures with speccy? That way I could look at the temperatures right before shutdown.

Comment: No that wont be working. If you want to get the error message from the last unexpected shutdown, you can always look in the event viewer from Windows itself: Start --> Run --> eventvwr.msc --> Custom views --> Administrative Events. Look there for the message at the time just before or just after the shutdown.

Comment: so that would be a definite way of finding out whats happening right before my computer is shutting down?

Comment: That would be a definite way of finding out why your computer is shutting down.

Comment: @JonathanLin Speed fan has a log (`configure` > `log` > `enabled` then goto to `configure` > `temperatures` > select a temperature > tick `logged`)